# Pandas lambda would not work on my dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, rolling-computation

I’m replicating YT code -along ( https://youtu.be/SYrFhugaoZk   on about 10th minute) in Jupyter nb, with pandas, and I was able to do it on their set, but not on mine. I get 10+ min of running, with no end and I stop manually the Kernel execution. This happened many times. Why? They have about 600000 rows, I have 1,500,000 - less then 3 times larger set. Both datasets have datetime as index, and other fields, but what I’m trying pertains to one column using pandas rolling function while applying lambda to each two rows.

```
    data['Target'] = sp500.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1] > x.iloc[0])['Close']  #this runs “endlessly”.
```

The original data set runs 3-5 seconds. Why? Any ideas?

2. Also, when I do it on smaller sets, I get the calculation,
   which I see when doing df.column.head(), but when I assign that column to the set and see df.head(), I get that column with all NaN’s. The values had become NaN’s. Weird pandas.
   Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If need compare shifted values no rolling necessary, use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html), convert to integers and omit first value (for NaN):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Close':[2,4,5,4,5,7,1,3]}).div(100)

df['Target'] = df['Close'].shift().lt(df['Close']).astype(int).iloc[1:]
df['Target1'] = df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1] > x.iloc[0])['Close']
print (df)
   Close  Target  Target1
0   0.02     NaN      NaN
1   0.04     1.0      1.0
2   0.05     1.0      1.0
3   0.04     0.0      0.0
4   0.05     1.0      1.0
5   0.07     1.0      1.0
6   0.01     0.0      0.0
7   0.03     1.0      1.0
```

EDIT: If duplicates solution is similar, only change solution for set missing values to first value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Close':[2,4,5,4,5,7,1,3]}, index=[1,1,2,2]*2).div(100)

df['Target'] = df['Close'].shift().lt(df['Close']).astype(int)
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Target')] = np.nan

df['Target1'] = df.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1] > x.iloc[0])['Close']
print (df)
   Close  Target  Target1
1   0.02     NaN      NaN
1   0.04     1.0      1.0
2   0.05     1.0      1.0
2   0.04     0.0      0.0
1   0.05     1.0      1.0
1   0.07     1.0      1.0
2   0.01     0.0      0.0
2   0.03     1.0      1.0
```

Comment: on this:
           tt['Target_X_lt'] = tt['Actual_Close'].shift().lt(tt['Actual_Close']).astype(int).iloc[1:]  
 I get:    ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: on the Series.lt i get: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Do you have an idea why? The rolling() works- but very slow.

Comment: @tonycornikolauos - Answer was edited.